# How to get class name for static main method

Tags: java

I need class name for public static void main method. Eg for my class name is GetClassName so output statement was **not** printed **GetClassName**

```
public class GetClassName {

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {

        System.out.println(getClass().getName().toString());

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use `GetClassName.class.getName()`. The whole point of a static method is that the class it's on will never change.

Answer (score 1):

You can get it from static context, unless explicitly specifying the class. For example:

```
System.out.println(GetClassName.class.getName());
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try like this:

```
GetClassName.class.getName();
```

This will give you  class name with package as well. OR

```
 GetClassName.class.getSimpleName();
```

This will give you only class name.

**[IDEONE DEMO](https://ideone.com/UjRiVC)**

Answer (score 1):

should be

```
System.out.println(GetClassName.class.getName());
```

No need for `.toString()` method, method already return `String`